# I need to pass multiple arrays back to the model

Tags: c#, arrays, model, formcollection

```
  List<siplist> itemList = new List<siplist>();    

 string AUNT= form["Amount"].Trim();    result  123,1234,123
 string Date = form["Date"].Trim();     result  2020-02-18,2020-02-17,2020-02-16
 string index = form["index"].Trim();   result 1,4,6

       itemList.Add(new siplist()
            {
                 Date= form["Date"].Trim()

            });
```

I want get result  as

```
{index :1 ,Date: 2020-02-18 ,Aunt:123},{index :4 ,Date: 2020-02-17 ,Aunt:1234}
```

I want to get the result is LIST return VIEW TO MODEL

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
List<siplist> itemList = new List<siplist>();
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    itemList.Add(new siplist() { index = index.Split(',')[i], Date = Date.Split(',')[i], Aunt = AUNT.Split(',')[i] });
}
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemList));
```

OUTPUT

```
[
    {
        "index": "1",
        "Date": "2020-02-18",
        "Aunt": "123"
    },
    {
        "index": "4",
        "Date": "2020-02-17",
        "Aunt": "1234"
    },
    {
        "index": "6",
        "Date": "2020-02-16",
        "Aunt": "123"
    }
]
```

Comment: Will the list I get have? list[0] 2020-03-04,2020-03-05,2020-03-17 ,list[1] 2020-03-04 ,list [2]2020-03-05 list[3]2020-03-17